# Add different text depending on URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, text, addition

Hi there I need to do something I thinks a bit complicated.

I need to add different text to a DIV depending on the URL, I know what the URL will be in each case (there are 6), so I need the javascript (jquery) to do this I just done know how to do it myself.

Thanks, Dave.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
 function showDiv() {
 var url = window.location.href;
 if (/(Electric-Mobility)/i.test(url)) {
 document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="none";
 }
 else {
 document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="block";
 }
  }
 </script>
 <body onload = "showDiv()" >
```

This sort of  works but doesnt do what i want and also does after page load.

these are the URL 
    ../brands/Electric-Mobility.html?sort=priceasc
    ../brands/Pride.html?sort=priceasc
    ../brands/Medical.html?sort=priceasc
    ../brands/Princey.html?sort=priceasc
    ../brands/NHC.html?sort=priceasc
    ../Roma.html?sort=priceasc

for each Url I need different text in div #content_hide

Hope this is clearer

Thanks
    New code

```
    <script type="text/javscript">
    function showDiv() {
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (/(Electric-Mobility)/i.test(url)){

    // i changed your old script using jQuery
    $("#content_hide").css("display","none");
     } else {
   $("#content_hide").css("display","block");
   }


   var myURL = url.split('?');
    var myTexts = ["text1","text2","text3"];
     switch(myURL[0]){
        case "http://www.youngsmobility.co.uk/brands/Electric-Mobility.html":
         $("#content_hide").html(myTexts[0]);
     break;
      case "http://www.youngsmobility.co.uk/brands/Pride.html":
     $("#content_hide").html(myTexts[1]);
      break;
     }
     } 
   </script>

    <body onload = "showDiv()" >
```

Up date to Code

```
     function showDiv() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var myURL = url.split('?');
    var myTexts = ["text1","text2","text3"];
     switch(myURL[0]){
     case "www.youngsmobility.co.uk/brands/Electric-Mobility.html":
     $("#content_hide").html(myTexts[0]);
     break;
     case "www.youngsmobility.co.uk/brands/Pride.html":
     $("#content_hide").html(myTexts[1]);
     break;
    }
     } 
     </script>

   <body onload = "showDiv()"
```

Comment: @mobilitydave where do you get this URL from adress bar or links

Answer (score 3):

```
switch(location.href) {
    case "http://example.com/page1":
        // put text for page1 in div
        break;
    // add more cases as needed
    // optionally add a default case.
}
```

That should get you going.

Comment: The URL will come from the actual URL of the page. So page A load I would want text A showing or Hide all other div except for Div A etc.  So for I have this but it doesnt work.                                         <script type = "text/javascript">
function showDiv() {
var url = window.location.href;
if (/(Electric-Mobility)/i.test(url)) {
document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="none";
}
else {
document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="block";
}
}    </script>

Answer (score 1):

```
function showDiv() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (/(Electric-Mobility)/i.test(url)){

    // i changed your old script using jQuery
    $("#content_hide").css("display","none");
    } else {
    $("#content_hide").css("display","block");
    }
    // my script start here
    var myURL = url.split('?');
    var myTexts = ["text1","text2","text3"];

    switch(myURL[0]){
     case "url1.html":
         $("#div_id").html(myTexts[0]);
     break;
     case "url2.html":
         $("#div_id").html(myTexts[1]);
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: mgraph will give your solution a go now will report back thanks

Comment: Does not seem to be working..could this be because the end of my URL his ...html?sort=priceasc

Comment: Hi again Im now useing this but it load page first then changes the div can I do it before page loads thanks.[code]<body onload = "showDiv()" >
<script type = "text/javascript">

function showDiv() {
var url = window.location.href;
if (/(Electric-Mobility)/i.test(url)) {
document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="none";
}
else {
document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="block";
}
}
</script>

Comment: Hi Tried the above script but didnt do anything..sorry! editi my original post with more info...thanks

Comment: @mobilitydave have you change `case "url1.html":...`

Comment: @mobilitydave  before `</head>` add this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: updated to version 1.7.1 now    have added my code  to original post hope this helps

Comment: @mobilitydave also change `$("#div_id")` by your div id i guess it's  `$("#content_hide")`

Comment: yes $("#div_id") is changed to $(#"content_hide") with "" inplace is that correct

Comment: @mobilitydave not correct, must be like that `$("#content_hide")`

Comment: just a type in my comment it it in fact $("#content_hide") the full code is in my original post now for clarity. do I need the first bit of code my stuff do i not just need your code?

Comment: comment `//$("#content_hide").css("display","none");` or remove it

Comment: Ok remove those bit still no good..I think I must be doing something wrong i will post the new code at top of page in original post, I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Sorry still no text being added to div

Comment: @mobilitydave add an alert before `switch(myURL[0]){` exmple `alert(myURL[0]);` what do you get ?

Comment: @mobilitydave did you include this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  before `</head>`

Comment: ok have done that but still no goo I have a javascript error in firebug saying showDiv not defined

Comment: @mobilitydave remove it from `<body>` and add it like that `$(document).ready(function(){showDiv();});   function showDiv() {....`

Comment: Ok I put the script through an online javascript begugger and I get this error      missing default case in switch statement

Comment: @mobilitydave does it works or not, `default` is not important

Comment: No does not work..so sorry!..what about this instead unhide a div depending on url...therefore I will have 6 div with content in them all hidden (with css) then depending on which url unhide div.??

Comment: or what about if url == then append some text

Comment: Hi again..I have come up (from another site) this     <script type="text/javascript"> 
function showMyDiv() {
if (window.location.href == "http://www.youngsmobility.co.uk/brands/Electric-Mobility.html?sort=priceasc") { 
document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="block";
}
else {
document.getElementById("content_hide").style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
    

 <body onload = "showMyDiv()">                                   this work but only after page has loaded any way to make this work before page renders?....thanks again

Comment: Thanks for all your help I have now sorted with some other code. again I appreciate your help.  davemobility